# Hide 'X people use this app' in the Facebook Auth Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication

Is there a way to hide the 'X friends and Y people use this app' in our Facebook authentication page?

Answer (score 3):

I don’t really know, but I would try turning “social discovery” off in the advanced app settings.

> *“Developers of app associated with more personal behavior such as dating, weight management or pregnancy, can turn these stories* [Discovery stories published in feed if user starts using an app] *off by disabling the social discovery field in the App Dashboard in the ‘On Facebook’ tab under the ‘Canvas’ section.”* [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/]

Would be only consistent if this disabled displaying “friends who use this app” as well. But with Facebook, you never know, so just give it a try.

If this doesn’t work, then I don’t know of any other way to do that.

Comment: @lgy is this disable displaying “friends who use this app”?

Comment: Did you test it? I believe yes

Comment: @lgy i disabled social  discovery in advanced settings.Still i m able to see friends used this app.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a configurable part of the Auth Dialog currently.

[Source from Developer Support Engineering team at Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11870586/1045444)

Answer (score -1):

Well indeed Facebook is changing again and again. In the button, set show_faces to false. This works for me now, hope this works for you too.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:login-button
   perms="email"
   width="width_value"
   show_faces="false"
   autologoutlink="true"
   size="medium">
   Login with Facebook
</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: The question was about the authentication dialog, not the login button plugin