# Hide the "X friends use this app" message in the auth dialog

Tags: facebook, installation, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I am developing a FB app where it is very negative to know that none or very few of your friends are using the app at time of installation.

Is there a way to hide the "X friends use this app" message in the auth dialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a configurable part of the Auth Dialog

Comment: If I add this app to the App Center, seems that there this message can be avoided disabling the "Social Discovery", Right?

Comment: Not that I know of, i think social discovery refers to the 'games you may like' units, etc